how $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{K}/K)$ acts on automorphisms of a $\overline{K}$-scheme
Let $K$ be a number field and $\overline{K}$ its algebraic closure. Let $(X,\mathcal{O}_{X},s)$ be a scheme over $\overline{K}$ where $s\colon X\to\mathrm{Spec}\overline{K}$ is the structural morphism. (In a specific example I am trying to write, $X$ is a projective curve over $K$ and then I make a base change to $X\times_{\mathrm{Spec}K}\mathrm{Spec}\overline{K}$.)
Let $\mathrm{Aut}_{\overline{K}}(X)$ be the automorphisms of $X$ as a $\overline{K}$-scheme. I want to define an action of $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{K}/K)$ on $\mathrm{Aut}_{\overline{K}}(X)$.
Here is what I have set up so far.
Let $\sigma\in\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{K}/K)$. There is a natural embedding $K\hookrightarrow\overline{K}$:
Taking spec reverses the arrows:
Let $(f,f^{\#})\in\mathrm{Aut}_{\overline{K}}(X)$. Then the following diagram commutes:
I want to define $\sigma.(f,f^{\#})$.
Then I think using the same morphism $(f,f^{\#})$, we can define an automorphism of $X$ as a $\overline{K}$-scheme but with the structural morphism as $s\circ\sigma^{\#}$. So the following diagram commutes:

and $\sigma.(f,f^{\#})$ is the same map as $(f,f^{\#})$, but just $(X,\mathcal{O}_{X},s\circ\sigma^{\#})\to(X,\mathcal{O}_{X},s\circ\sigma^{\#})$ instead of $(X,\mathcal{O}_{X},s)\to(X,\mathcal{O}_{X},s)$.
But I don't know if this is a valid group action because we are using an automorphism of $X$ realised as a $\overline{K}$-scheme via $s$ to define an automorphism of $X$ realised as a $\overline{K}$-scheme via $s\circ\sigma^{\#}$, so I don't know if $\sigma.(f,f^{\#})$ is an element of the original $\mathrm{Aut}_{\overline{K}}(X)$. I guess before that, I should ask whether $\mathrm{Aut}_{\overline{K}}(X)$ should be thought of as "fixing" a structural morphism on $X$ or not, and maybe that will give me a better idea on the right way to define an action.
I would appreciate any explanation or advice on how to think about how a galois group can act on automorphisms of $X$. Thank you very much in advance.

As usual, try the affine case first.

I also struggled with these kind of Galois action on schemes issues when I first encountered them. I am no expert, but let me share what I learned and what makes sense to me today. The field $K$ need not be a number field.
If you consider any scheme $X$ over $\mathrm{Spec}(\overline{K})$, there is no reason that any (nontrivial) $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{K}/K)$ action should be defined, neither on $X$ nor on its automorphism group. Indeed, the choice of $K$ is arbitrary, you are asking if a scheme over an algebraically closed field $\Omega$ has a $\mathrm{Gal}(\Omega/K)$ action for any algebraic subextension $K$. Think of $X$ as being defined by some equation involving lots of elements of $\Omega$, you would struggle to define some Galois action on $X$ for ANY subextention which preserves the solutions of that equation. I believe a similar kind of obstruction occurs with the automorphism group.
As you mention in your attempt, $\mathrm{Aut}_{\overline{K}}(X)$ is thought of as automorphisms of $X$ preserving the structural map to $\mathrm{Spec}(\overline{K})$, which your map $f \mapsto\sigma \cdot f$ does not. Concretely, for instance, your attempt maps an automorphism of $\mathrm{Spec}(\overline{\Bbb Q}[X,Y]/(P(X,Y)))$ to an automorphism of $\mathrm{Spec}(\overline{\Bbb Q}[X,Y]/(\sigma(P)(X,Y)))$ (maybe there is a $\sigma^{-1}$ instead...). This is not a pointless definition however, as I believe it is one way to define the Frobenius automorphism on schemes in positive characteristic (I may be wrong...).
Now if $X$ is defined over a field $K$, i.e. if $X$ is obtained as the base change $Y \times_{K}\overline{K}$ of a $K$-scheme (such as in your original motivation), then we will see that there is a natural $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{K}/K)$ action on $X$, which then induces an action on $\mathrm{Aut}_{\overline{K}}(X)$. This is for instance the case when dealing with schemes of finite type over $\overline{K}$: $X$ can be covered by a finite number of spectra of affine $\overline{K}$-algebra, which are themselves defined by a finite number of equations, hence involve only a finite number of elements of $\overline{K}$ ; if $L/\Bbb Q$ (or $\Bbb F_p$ in characteristic $p$) is a finite extension containing all these coefficients, then all these affine $\overline{K}$-algebras are obtained as affine $L$-algebras tensored with $\overline{K}$, i.e. $X = Y \times_L \overline{K}$ is defined over $L$. For instance, $\mathrm{Spec}(\overline{\Bbb Q}[X,Y]/(\sqrt{7}Y^2 - iX^3 +\sqrt[3]{5}X^2+X))$ is an elliptic curve over $\overline{\Bbb Q}$, which is defined over $\Bbb Q[i, \sqrt{7}, \sqrt[3]{5}]$.
So now assume that $X = Y \times_K \overline{K}$ is defined over $K$, and let $\sigma \in \mathrm{Gal}(\overline{K}/K)$. We can use the map $\mathrm{id} \times \sigma : X \rightarrow X$ (denoted $\sigma$) to define the following $K$-automorphism of $X$:

Notice that while this is not an isomorphism over $\overline{K}$, we can "undo" the twist when dealing with $\mathrm{Aut}_{\overline{K}}(X)$. Let $f \in \mathrm{Aut}_{\overline{K}}(X)$, define $\sigma \cdot f$ as the composition of the top three arrow:

The bottom three arrows compose to the identity, hence $\sigma \cdot f \in \mathrm{Aut}_{\overline{K}}(X)$. You can easily check that this defines an action. Similarly, you can define a Galois action on $\mathrm{Hom}_{\overline{K}}(X,Z)$, where $X$ and $Z$ are two $\overline{K}$ schemes defined over $K$, by the same "twist and untwist" trick.
That was probably overkill, but I hope this answers your question.
